# How to access variables of Jquery in FTL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

I am using `FTL` very first time. I want to access `ancor tag`from this code in jquery within `FTL` file and want to give style for table through `jQuery`. But can't get the exact syntax. Please help me anyone.

**My FTL Code** :-

```
<#import "HeaderCommon.ftl" as c/>
     <@c.page title=" Manpreet Singh Title">
  <div>
    <table border="1" align="center" style="width:50%">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr.No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Website</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>

     <tbody> 
      <#assign c=merchantstemp.getOffset()+1>
     <#list merchantstemp.results as m >
            <tr>
                  <td>${m_index + c}</td>
                  <td>${m.name}</td>
                  <td>${m.website!""}</td>
            </tr>   
     </#list>   


    </tbody> 
    </table>
    </br>
    <center>
    <#assign n=merchantstemp.pgNum>
        <#if (merchantstemp.prevPages() > 0 && itemsPerPageStr?has_content) >

                <#if (n>=2)>    
                  <#assign j= n-2>  
                  <a href="/mer?pgNum=${j}&ipp=${itemsPerPageStr}">${j}</a>
                   <#assign i= n-1>
                   <a href="/mer?pgNum=${i}&ipp=${itemsPerPageStr}">${i}</a>
                     ${n}
                   <#assign k= n+1>
                   <a href="/mer?pgNum=${k}&ipp=${itemsPerPageStr}">${k}</a>
                   <#assign t= n+2>
                     <a href="/mer?pgNum=${t}&ipp=${itemsPerPageStr}">${t}</a>
                 </#if>
        <#else>

            <#if (n>=2)>  
             <#assign j= n-2>  
             <a href="/mer?pgNum=${j}">${j}</a>
             <#assign i= n-1>
             <a href="/mer?pgNum=${i}">${i}</a>
             ${n}
             <#assign k= n+1>
             <a href="/mer?pgNum=${k}">${k}</a>
             <#assign t= n+2>
             <a href="/mer?pgNum=${t}">${t}</a>
            </#if>
       </#if>


    <#if (merchantstemp.prevPages() > 0 && itemsPerPageStr?has_content) >

       <a href="/mer?pgNum=${merchantstemp.pgNum -1}&ipp=${itemsPerPageStr}"> &it;Pre;</a>

       <#else>
       <a href="/mer?pgNum=${merchantstemp.pgNum - 1}"> &it; Pre </a>
    </#if>

    <#if (merchantstemp.nextPages() > 0 && itemsPerPageStr?has_content) >
      <a href="/mer?pgNum=${merchantstemp.pgNum + 1}&ipp=${itemsPerPageStr}">Next &gt;</a>

    <#else>
    <a href="/mer?pgNum=${merchantstemp.pgNum + 1}">Next &gt;</a>
   </#if>

     </@c.page>
     </center>  
  </div>   
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Show All Merchants</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTL runs on the web server, jQuery runs in the browser after that. So FTL and JavaScript can't share variables, and only FTL can pass down values to JavaScript (via generating JavaScript assignment as output, for example). (Give a more focused demonstration of your problem if this haven't answered it.)